# Why is there a gap between the levers of my Tiagra 4700 shifter?

Tags: shimano, brifters

I just took delivery of a used 4700 groupset and noticed that the left shifter has a large gap between the brake lever and downshift lever. Anyone know why this is? Any solutions? It certainly doesn’t look right.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Here’s the right lever for comparison:

[image]

---

In regards to problem solving, I’d like to give it a try myself first before reverting to demanding a partial refund from the seller. The guy has good prices and I’d like to keep our relationship intact. Also, telling me to avoid brifters is not a productive recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diagnosis complete. The lever blade has a movement stop consisting of a small threaded rod butting up against a little “button”. See the right lever for reference:

[image]

Compare that to the left lever, which is missing the button (presumably a mushroom-shaped press-fit pin which fell out):

[image]

The missing button-shaped piece means that the lever blade can pivot outwards farther than intended before contacting the threaded rod.

---

#### UPDATE:

Repair complete. My idea of driving in a small screw worked great. I salvaged some screws from an old hard drive. The lever blade is soft aluminum and easily took threads, even with non-self-tapping screws. I could only use each screw for a couple revolutions before the heads stripped out from the high torque needed. After enough partial passes, I eventually created enough threads to drive one last screw all the way in.

[image]

Looks great now.

[image]

Comment: Nice spotting!  You could simply wind the adjuster screw in further, but it will press on the edges of the hole and over time make a mess.  Would be better to find something to go in the hole.  I've had good results using "5 second fix" which is UV-cured epoxy coming in a pen-like tube, with a UV flashlight/torch on the end.  Just build up layers of half-millimetre at a time.  Or you could try making a plug from brass, but that would be small and fiddly.   https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002060255786.html for example of UV epoxy

Comment: @Criggie I'm tempted to try to put a small screw into the hole, but your idea of machining a plug sounds better. Not so sure about the epoxy idea